# How to show loading message or dialog or image in an android activity while processing before the activity is finished?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-asynctask

I have an `Activity` "A1" and a `ListActivity` "A2"

I take inputs from user in `Activity` "A1" and depending on the inputs given by user I process and generate a result list. The list generated will then be shown in my `ListActivity` "A2".

Now, processing the inputs and generating the result list takes a bit too long. So I want to show a loading dialog or loading image or loading message in this time so the user won't think that the app is stuck up doing nothing.

Now the things I tried so far:
Yes, I tried `AsyncTask`! (I know many people are about to suggest it) So now I am doing all my processing in an `AsyncTask`. I am showing a `ProgressDialog` in `onPreExecute`, doing my processing in `doInBackground` and dismissing the dialog `onPostExecute`.

However, the dialog comes just before the `ListActivity` "A2" starts. Until then the `Activity` "A1" just seems to be stuck up!

I want the dialog to show up right when I click the "Submit" button on `Activity` "A1" and continue to be seen until `ListActivity` "A2" shows up.

Please let me know if you need anymore details. Thanks.

-***EDIT***-

Code in **onClick** method:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setMessage("Processing... Please Wait...");
progressDialog.show();
// Execute task
MyTask myTask = new MyTask(progressDialog);
AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> result =
    myTask.execute(userChoice);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListActivityA2.class);
// Put results in intent
intent.putExtra("results", resultsList);
// Start result activity
startActivity(intent);
```

**AsyncTask**

```
public class MyTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> resultsList =
                    new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        public MyTask(ProgressDialog progressDialog) {
            this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(
                String... params) {
            return doProcess(params[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doProcess(String choice) {

            // do processing here
            return arrayList;
        }
}
```

Comment: I'ld actually suggest you to start a progress bar on click; do your calculations inside it; stasrt Activity2 when it dismisses :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this!

I moved the code to create `Intent` to `onPostExecute`

The reason behind this: the UI thread (`Activity` "A1") was anyway waiting for the `AsyncTask` to return the results so that it could show the `ListActivity` "A2"

Now that the creating intent and starting `ListActivity` "A2" is happening in `onPostExecute` the UI thread can work without freezing.

Thanks for all ur help @Aswin Kumar!

Hope this question and answer helps others. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to show the dialog on clicking submit, dismiss it, and then show Activity A2 with the data filled in.

So you can do exactly that:

1. start the `AsyncTask` in `onClick` of Submit
2. show the `ProgressDialog`
3. do processing
4. `onPostExecute`, *save the data as an object to be passed to A2 via `Intent`*, dismiss the dialog, and start the list activity A2 with the saved data in an `Intent`
5. In activity A2, just parse the data passed in and display the list.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had already tried that. On clicking the button the `Activity` "A1" just freezes there (showing the button clicked) and then the `ProgressDialog` pops up just before the `ListActivity` "A2" loads.

Comment: If you see the button freezed while the operation is running, you are doing the processing on the UI thread (which you shouldn't be). Paste the code for `onClick()` of the button and the `AsyncTask` implementation, I might be able to help you out.

Comment: I have added code in the question. Please see and tell me what's wrong that I am doing. Thanks a lot for all your help! (I have changed variable names for simplicity)